# Create a item in SysListView32 with icons

Tags: c++, winapi, syslistview32

I'm trying to create a list view, a item with a icon, but i was created the item, but not the icon show.

I'm tried to pass `NULL`, resource index, and use `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` but it shows only the text, not the icon.

```
HWND CreateListView (HWND hwndParent) 
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;           // Structure for control initialization.
    icex.dwICC = ICC_LISTVIEW_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    RECT rcClient;                       // The parent window's client area.

    GetClientRect (hwndParent, &rcClient); 

    // Create the list-view window in report view with label editing enabled.
    HWND hWndListView = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, 
                                     "",
                                     WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
                                     0, 0,
                                     rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
                                     rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
                                     hwndParent,
                                     NULL,
                                     (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwndParent,GWL_HINSTANCE),
                                     NULL); 

    return (hWndListView);
}
VOID SetView(HWND hWndListView, DWORD dwView) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the current window style. 
    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hWndListView, GWL_STYLE); 
    
    // Set the window style only if the view bits changed.
    if ((dwStyle & LVS_TYPEMASK) != dwView) 
    {
        SetWindowLong(hWndListView,
                      GWL_STYLE,
                      (dwStyle & ~LVS_TYPEMASK) | dwView);
    }               // Logical OR'ing of dwView with the result of 
}                   // a bitwise AND between dwStyle and 
                    // the Unary complenent of LVS_TYPEMASK.
BOOL InitListViewColumns(HWND hWndListView, int C_COLUMNS, int FirstColumn) 
{ 
    LPSTR szText[256];     // Temporary buffer.
    LVCOLUMN lvc;
    int iCol;

    // Initialize the LVCOLUMN structure.
    // The mask specifies that the format, width, text,
    // and subitem members of the structure are valid.
    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;

    // Add the columns.
    for (iCol = 0; iCol < C_COLUMNS; iCol++)
    {
        lvc.iSubItem = iCol;
        lvc.pszText = (LPSTR)szText;
        lvc.cx = 100;               // Width of column in pixels.

        if ( iCol < 2 )
            lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;  // Left-aligned column.
        else
            lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_RIGHT; // Right-aligned column.

        // Load the names of the column headings from the string resources.
        LoadString((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong((HWND)GetWindowLong(hWndListView,GWL_HWNDPARENT),GWL_HINSTANCE),
                   FirstColumn + iCol,
                   (LPSTR)szText,
                   sizeof(szText)/sizeof(szText[0]));

        // Insert the columns into the list view.
        if (ListView_InsertColumn(hWndListView, iCol, &lvc) == -1)
            return FALSE;
    }
    
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL InsertListViewItems(HWND hWndListView, LPSTR text, LPVOID iImage)
{
    LVITEM lvI;

    // Initialize LVITEM members that are common to all items.
    lvI.pszText   = text; // Sends an LVN_GETDISPINFO message.
    lvI.cchTextMax= strlen(text);
    lvI.mask      = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE |LVIF_STATE;
    lvI.stateMask = 0;
    lvI.iSubItem  = 0;
    lvI.state     = 0;
    int index=ListView_GetItemCount(hWndListView)+1;
    lvI.iItem  = index;
    lvI.iImage = (int)iImage;
    
    // Insert items into the list.
    if (ListView_InsertItem(hWndListView, &lvI) == -1)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
BOOL InitListViewImageLists(HWND hWndListView, LPVOID IDI_ITEM, HINSTANCE hInstance) 
{ 
    HICON hiconItem;     // Icon for list-view items.
    HIMAGELIST hLarge;   // Image list for icon view.
    HIMAGELIST hSmall;   // Image list for other views.

    // Create the full-sized icon image lists. 
    hLarge = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON), 
                              GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON), 
                              ILC_MASK, 1, 1); 

    hSmall = ImageList_Create(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), 
                              GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 
                              ILC_MASK, 1, 1); 
    
    // Add an icon to each image list.  
    hiconItem = LoadIcon(hInstance,(LPCTSTR)IDI_ITEM);

    ImageList_AddIcon(hLarge, hiconItem);
    ImageList_AddIcon(hSmall, hiconItem);

    DestroyIcon(hiconItem);

    
    // Assign the image lists to the list-view control. 
    ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hLarge, LVSIL_NORMAL); 
    ListView_SetImageList(hWndListView, hSmall, LVSIL_SMALL); 
    
    return TRUE; 
}

    hWnd[1] = CreateListView((HWND)hWnd[0]);
    InitListViewImageLists((HWND)hWnd[1], NULL, NULL);
    SetView((HWND)hWnd[1], LVS_ICON);
    InitListViewColumns((HWND)hWnd[1], 1, IDS_FIRSTCOLUMN);
    InsertListViewItems((HWND)hWnd[1], "Windows", NULL);
```

For the build system: Microsoft Visual C/C++ 6.0

Comment: In `InitListViewColumns()`, your use of `szText` is wrong, it should be an array of `CHAR` not `LPCSTR`. In `InsertListViewItems()`, you are setting `lvI.iImage` to 0 (why are passing in the index as a type-casted `LPVOID`?), are you sure your image lists have a valid icon at index 0? And what is with all the type-casts everywhere? If you have to type-cast something, you likely aren't using the right type to begin with.

Comment: Please provide a correct reproducible minimal sample. There are a lot of errors in your code that cannot be compiled.

Comment: @torrecto Oh, it's from C++98, don't compile with Visual Studio 2022!

Comment: @RemyLebeau There are no LPCSTR in the code.

Comment: You really need to clean up the code as mentioned above, but you're passing `NULL` to `InitListViewImageLists()`and subsequently to `LoadIcon()`. This would be obvious with some minimal debugging on your part.

Comment: @winapiadmin sorry, I meant `LPSTR`, and there are several incorrect `LPSTR` uses in the code shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Luke and Remy Lebeau said, that's correct. I did pass the `NULL` to `InitListViewImageLists()` and `InsertListViewItems()`, while passing `NULL` to `InitListViewImageLists()` will create a image list with empty image on the image list.

So, I need to change the call to `InitListViewColumns()` and `InsertListViewItems()`

This is the new code:

```
    hWnd[1] = CreateListView((HWND)hWnd[0]);
    InitListViewImageLists((HWND)hWnd[1], IDI_DS, hInst);
    SetView((HWND)hWnd[1], LVS_ICON);
    InitListViewColumns((HWND)hWnd[1], 1, IDS_FIRSTCOLUMN);
    InsertListViewItems((HWND)hWnd[1], "Windows", 0);
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If so, it should identify the issue and explain how the proposed solution addresses it.

Comment: By the way, it is necessary to initialize the array, otherwise using handle variables may have unexpected surprises.

Comment: Nobody changes the code without testing. And handles are not initialize-able at design time, default it's NULL (0L), they are always initialized, and they must be created from functions.